# Iterating and adding elements to a list that contains multiple dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list that contains multiple dictionaries with two keys, using a for loop, I'm trying to add elements to the first and second keys of each dictionary, however im not getting the expected output. the expected output that im hoping for for the following code would be:

```
   XPECTED =====[{'parts':[2],F[]},{'parts':[3],F[]}] 
   a=[2,3]
   list_combined=[]
   dict={'parts':[],'F':[]}


    for c in range(0,5):
      list_combined.append(dict)
      list_combined[c]['parts']=a[c]
```

Comment: 1) Your "expected" is not valid Python syntax for a dictionary - `{'parts':[2],F[]}` is not valid, try assigning it to a variable and you'll get a syntax error.  2) your code adds dict to list_combined five times, so it can't create a list with only two elements. Please edit into your questions a [mre] that works. Debugging is actually the most skilled part of writing software - use a debugger, or add print statements to make visible the data your code is operating on - just learning to do simple debugging like that will mean you will ask fewer questions on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

1) The `range(0, 5)` will cause index error when you try to access `a[c]`

2) You are using the same dictionary in each iteration - so you keep modifying the same dictionary. You need to make a copy instead.

3) To get a list in `parts` you need to set that key to a list.

```
a = [2,3]
list_combined = []
d = {'parts': [], 'F': []}

for c in range(0, 2):
    list_combined.append(d.copy())
    list_combined[c]['parts'] = [a[c]]

print(list_combined)
```

Output:

```
[{'parts': [2], 'F': []}, {'parts': [3], 'F': []}]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear if the dictionary is created or modified but you can try this:

```
list_combined = [{'parts':[u],'F':[]} for u in a]
```

Also don't name your dictionary as `dict` because it is a keywords from Python.